# Reduce to a single differential

Tags: calculus, derivatives, partial-differential-equations

I am trying to model the fluid flow within a deformable annulus. I'm currently stucked with a particular nasty term

$-\frac{1}{k}A_c\frac{Q}{A^2}\frac{\partial}{\partial z}(kQ)+\frac{1}{k}\frac{\partial}{\partial z}(k\frac{Q^2}{A})$

Everything, a part from $A_c$ which is constant, depends on $z$. The coefficient $k$ is defined as $k=1-\frac{A_c}{A}$.

I would like, if possible to express it as a single differential, something like $\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}$ with $f$ to be determined. Does anybody have a suggestion? Thank you very much!

Comment: Are you asking if this is a total differential ?

Comment: essentially yes

Comment: Essentially, it is not.

Comment: yeah that's the same impression I had. I had the hope that I was missing something. Thanks!